# window.width() doesn't work properly on lower screen resolution

Tags: jquery, function

I want to run a function if right side of a div is clicked, and another function if left side is clicked (div is horizontally centered inside html).

```
 $("#div01").click(function (e) {
     if (e.pageX > $(window).width() / 2)(changeUp())
     else(changeDown());
 });
```

Works well on screen resolution 1024x768 and higher (without horizontal scroll bar on the screen), but it doesn't work properly on lower (800x600) resolution, when horizontal scroll appears. In that case I need to click more left to run `changeDown()`.

Any help, pls;

Comment: i don't know if i am wrong, but your brackets at the if and else looks wrong: () instead of { } but this isn't the problem. you can use console.log to see how high the window is. Maybe the window has always the same high butt the body (document) is higher!

Comment: @Mic, I replaced `()` widh `{}` and got an Firebug error: `SyntaxError: missing ( before condition`

Comment: look in the first answer. maybe is discribed it to bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#div01").click(function(e) {
     if (e.pageX > $(window).width() / 2) {
       changeUp();
     }
     else {
       changeDown();
     }
 });
```

Comment: draxxxeus, your brackets work, but the calculation of screenMiddle point remains the wrong.

Comment: What are you expecting and what is the output?

Comment: draxxxeus, I want to run a function if right side of a div is clicked, and another function if left side is clicked (div is horizontally centered inside html)... please read my question on the top